# Verificar se uma data é anterior a outra data

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia, gostaria de saber se existe um jeito de verificar se uma data é anterior ou superior a outra, no meu código tem 2 inputs tipo date, que enviam seus valores ao banco de dados, porém uma data irá iniciar algo e a outra finalizara, gostaria de fazer um verificação antes de enviar ao banco que não permita que a primeira data seja maior que a segunda, tem como fazer isso?

FORM:

```html
<tr>
    <th>Data de Inicio:</th>
    <td><input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" name="Data_Inicio" required><br></td>
</tr>  
<tr>
    <th>Data de Encerramento:</th>
    <td><input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" name="Data_fim" required><br></td>
</tr>
```

PHP:

```php
$Data01 = explode("-", $Data_in);
$Data02 = explode("-", $Data_fim);
$Ndata_in = $Data01[0] . '/' . $Data01[1] . '/' . $Data01[2];
$Ndata_fim = $Data02[0] . '/' . $Data02[1] . '/' . $Data02[2];

$sql = 'INSERT INTO walldata VALUES ("' . $Ndata_in . '", "' . $Ndata_fim . '")';
```

Comment: Você está fazendo do jeito mais difícil. Vou tentar te ajudar

Comment: Okay Wallace Obrigado :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A forma mais correta é:

```
$data1 = new DateTime( '2016-06-06' );
$data2 = new DateTime( '2016-06-15' );

echo ($data1 < $data2) ? "Está Ok!" : "Data de encerramento errada";
```

Na *query* você pode usar só a `string` da data pura mesmo nesse formato `1996-12-10 (aaaa-mm-dd)`

Comment: Ok, obrigado mas isso ai vai servir para verificar as datas, para saber qual é se são válidas, ex: $data_in = 19/01/2000 , $data_fim = 18/01/2000, erro a data de encerramento deve ser maior do que a de inicio, espero ter explicado bem :D

Comment: Não entendi muito bem kk o código da resposta verifica se uma data é menor que a outra, onde `$data1` é o inicio e `$data2` é o final. Já para verificar se uma data é válida não é necessário, pois o html5 faz isso. Caso queira validar se a data é maior que a data atual é só usar `$data1 = new DateTime( date() );`

Comment: Entendi oque você quis dizer obrigado

Answer (score 4):

O colega @lvcs já deu um exemplo bom do uso do `Datetime`, mas eu não poderia deixar de dizer que se as datas forem strings no formato já usado pelo MySQL, no formato `AAAA-MM-DD`, é desnecessário instanciar dois objetos `DateTime`.

Muito mais simples e eficiente fazer a comparação diretamente:

```
$data_menor = '2016-06-01';
$data_maior = '2016-02-31';

echo ( $data_menor  < $data_maior ) ? "Está Ok!" : "Data de encerramento errada";
```

Se quiser inverter automaticamente também é simples:

```
$data_menor = '2016-06-01';
$data_maior = '2016-02-31';

if( $data_menor > $data_maior ) {
   $tmp = $data_maior ;
   $data_maior = $data_menor ;
   $data_menor = $tmp;
}

$sql = 'INSERT INTO walldata VALUES ("' . $data_menor . '", "' . $data_maior . '")';
```

<sub>PS: a troca de variáveis acima é muito mais veloz do que fazer `list($x,$y) = array($y,$x);`</sub>

Answer (score 1):

"fazer um verificação antes de enviar ao banco que não permita que a primeira data seja maior que a segunda"

Vc pode fazer isso de duas maneiras diferentes:

1. Back end - php
2. Front end - javascript

Eu geralmente uso javascript para evitar código em php.
Dito isso, usando JS, existem ao menos 2 possibilidades para essa tarefa.

1. Usando javascript puro
2. Usando algum das várias bibliotecas JS. Eu uso [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) do jquery.

Essa aplicação permite várias configurações do campo de data de maneira bem simples.

Eu tenho um código que uso nas minhas aplicações. Ele é bi direcional.
No cenário seguinte existe uma data para entregar produtos e uma data para relaizar a festa. Então o usuário escolhe a data prevista para receber o produto. Quando essa data é escolhida, a data da festa só pode ser maior ou igual a data de chegada. Existe tbm a possibilidade do usuário escolher primeiro a data da festa. Entáo a data máxima de entrega do produto só pode ser a data do evento.

Espero que ajude, tenta adequar para suas necessidades.

```
    //Validar datas:

    //Quando abre o datapicker seleciona a menor data para ser o dia de hoje now().
    var now = new Date(),
    minDateJS = now.toISOString().substring(0,10);

    //Seleciona a data de entrega do produto.
    //Aplica a data now (hoje) para ser a menor data selecionavel para a entrega do produto
    //Aplica a data de entrega do produto para ser a menor data possivel do evento  
    $('#dt_entregaProd').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: minDateJS,
        inline: true,         
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {//Passa a data selecionada neste objeto para ser a menor data possivel para realizar o evento
          $( "#dt_Event" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }

    });             


    //Seleciona a data do evento.
    //Evento bidirecional. Se a data do evento for selecionada primeiro, entã a data máxima de entrega do produto será limitada automaticamente
    $('#dt_Event').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: minDateJS,
        inline: true, 
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
          $( "#dt_entregaProd" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }        
     });
```